# Nodejs express user registration that checks whether a username or email already exist in mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do i check whether a username or email already exist in mongodb database during user registration process in node.js express application and then notify the user that username or email already is taken. 
here is my code

```
var usernameQuery = {username: username};
  User.findOne(usernameQuery, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(user){
      req.flash('info', 'Username already taken');
      return res(false);
    }
  });

  var emailQuery = {email: email};
  User.findOne(emailQuery, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(user){
      req.flash('info', 'Email already taken');
      return res(false);
    }
  });
```

Comment: So... this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Use mongodb `$or` operator and `count` method to check that there is a record with the same `username` or `email`:

```
User.count({
  $or: [
    { username },
    { email }
  ] 
})
.then(cnt => {
  if (cnt > 0) {
    req.flash('info', 'Username or Email already taken');
    return res.send({ success: false });
  }
  res.send({ success: true });
})
.cath(err => // TODO process error)
```